# In R's dplyr, create a column specifying which of the other columns are TRUE

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

I have a logical data frame:

```
df = data_frame(x = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), y = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), z = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE))

df
  # A tibble: 4 x 3
    x     y     z
  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
1  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
2  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

I would like to create a fourth column that indicates, possibly using commas, which of the 3 columns in every row have the value TRUE, i.e. for row 1 the value would be (1, 3).

I can do it with a loop, but need to do it with large data sets so would prefer a vectorized dplyr solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need the column names, then `gather` into 'long' format and then `paste` the column names that corresponds to the TRUE value and create a new column in 'df'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>%
  summarise(val = toString(key[val])) %>% 
  pull(val) %>%
  mutate(df, val = .)
```

---

If we only need the column indices, use `which` on the 'val' column generated in the 'long' format

```
df %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>%
  gather(key, val, -rn) %>% 
  group_by(rn) %>% 
  summarise(val = toString(which(val))) %>%
  pull(val) %>% 
  mutate(df, val = .)
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  x     y     z     val  
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <chr>
#1 T     F     T     1, 3 
#2 T     F     T     1, 3 
#3 F     F     F     ""   
#4 T     T     F     1, 2
```

---

We can also do this with `rowwise` and `do`

```
df %>%
   rowwise() %>%
   do(data.frame(., val = toString(which(unlist(.)))))
```

---

Or we can do this with `base R` with some regex as well

```
df$val <- gsub("0,*|,0$", "", do.call(paste, c(col(df) * df, sep=",")))
df$val
#[1] "1,3" "1,3" ""    "1,2"
```

Comment: Thanks! very thorough answer